# Which registers can be safely used in x64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

In the x64 assembly there are the registers `rsp` and `rip` which respectively contain the pointers to the current stack frame and the next instruction.

I know that the `rax, rdx, ...` registers are used for the return value.

Is it safe to do anything I want with the remaining general-purpose registers? In particular, can I leave the `r8-r15` registers filled with anything without affecting the further program runtime?

Comment: You can use safely any register, as long as you know what you are doing. You can modify any register, which you know the further program doesn't expect to be preserved. To know which registers are GENERALLY preserved on your platform, check it's ABI documentation (it's not clear what is your platform, only that it is x86_64). (but you can still get away even by modifying one of those, if you know the rest of the program doesn't use it ... if we are talking about some generic C/C++ code calling your assembly, then conform to the ABI by 100%, because you never know how the C/C++ will compile).

Comment: We can assume that my platform is an Intel or AMD 64-bit CPU. Where can I find the ABI documentation? I found something like System V Application Binary Interface, but I don't know whether it's that

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: Each OS has different ABI. The "System V" (old UNIX related) is relevant for linux 64b (I'm not sure whether there were some minor modifications over time, in the very early days, so rather verify twice it's up to date with linux64, if that's your platform. Or just search for "ABI" here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: I'm programming for Linux, I'd like to keep POSIX compatibility